# Same eigenvectors in a matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

When can a left and the right eigenvector be same? what would the matrix have to be like for it? would the matrix have to have some property for this to happen?

According to the following lecture: http://control.ucsd.edu/mauricio/courses/mae280a/lecture11.pdf

symmetric matrix has orthogonal eigenvectors. Could that be the answer?

Comment: If the matrix is square and the eigenvector is $v$ then, with respect to the decomposition $\mathbb C^n = span\,\{v\}\oplus v^\perp$ the matrix has the representation$$\begin{pmatrix}\lambda & 0\\0 & A'\end{pmatrix},$$ where $\lambda$ is the eigenvalue.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp how is this related to my question?

Comment: You asked 4 questions. I answered the second and the third.